# How to get better video quality using Accord.Video.FFMPEG.DLL

Tags: visual-studio-code, ffmpeg, video-processing, codec, mpeg

I have developed a Visual Studio Winapp that produces a video file utilizing Accord.Video.FFMPEG.DLL.

The quality the video is less than the original images.
Here is the code and then a sample original image and snapshot of the resulting video.

What can I change to improve the video image?

```
            VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
            writer.Open(outfile, width, height, 1, VideoCodec.Mpeg4);
            for (int i = firstrow; i <= testframes; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(ffiles[i, 0].ToString());
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap);
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
```

I tried Bitmap image = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple configurations, and it looks like using VP9 codec and WebM file gives the best quality.
We may also set the bitRate argument to high value.

Code sample:

```c#
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
using Accord.Math;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Testings
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap tmp_bitmap = new Bitmap(@"Image640x480.png");
            int width = tmp_bitmap.Width; //640
            int height = tmp_bitmap.Height; //480
            tmp_bitmap.Dispose();

            VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
            //writer.Open(@"outfile.mp4", width, height, new Rational(1, 1), VideoCodec.H264);
            writer.Open(@"outfile.webm", width, height, new Rational(1, 1), VideoCodec.VP9, 50000000);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"Image640x480.png");  //For the example, I used the same image.
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap);
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }

            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note:
The output colors doesn't seem accurate, and there are multiple options that doesn't work.
Instead of using Accord, I recommend using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) CLI, or looking for a better package.

Comment: I found the most improvement by increasing the width\height to 840x680 with original codec.
The VP9 codec caused the first frame to be displayed for 5 seconds before the frames started changing (odd).  

Now if I could get the playback to move faster, but I guess that is a function of disk speed\buffering\CPU speed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The current frame rate is 1fps. For faster playback increase the framerate. Try `(25, 1)`

Comment: Where does that go?  New Rational(25,1)?  Somewhere else?

Comment: Yes `new Rational(25, 1)` for setting the rate to 25 frames per second (assuming that what you meant by "get the playback to move faster").

Answer (score 0):

Use videocodec.H264 in the open function it will give better output.